# Compiling with cx_freeze doesn't produce expected files

Tags: python

First of all, I must say THANK YOU A LOT!, this site and the questions made here are a great source of info.

Forgive my english, I'm not used to write and/or express long ideas.

Well, now I expose my trouble: I'm writing a python program that deals with matrices, the user enter some data needed to assemble them and do some matrix-operations. At the end of calculations, the program must write the results of calculations in a .txt file. Must say that everything works as suposed when I run the program in python's shell.

Now, since I want to distribute this program stand-alone (in other words, the program runs without calling python's shell), I moved to W7 and installed cx_Freeze and all stuff needed. Runs the compiling command and get no errors. Runs the program and get no errors (I think) but the .txt file was not created!

I show a snippet of code from the mainprogram (variable names are in spanish) that deals with file writing:

```
...
reporte = open(r'reporte_%s.txt' % g_fecha, 'w')
reporte.write('+' + '-'*39 + '+\n')
reporte.write('|' + ' '*10 + 'PROGRAMA CERCHAS 2D' + ' '*10 + '|\n')
reporte.write('|' + ' '*39 + '|\n')
reporte.write('|' + ' '*7 + 'Software didáctico para ' + ' '*8 + '|\n')
reporte.write('|' + ' '*3 + 'análisis de cerchas estáticamente' + ' '*3 + '|\n')
reporte.write('|' + ' '*5 + 'determinadas e indeterminadas' + ' '*5 + '|\n')
reporte.write('|' + ' '*39 + '|\n')
reporte.write('|' + ' '*14 + 'versión 1.0' + ' '*14 + '|\n')
reporte.write('|' + ' '*5 + 'Desarrollado por: Felipe Pérez' + ' '*4 + '|\n')
reporte.write('|' + ' '*3 + 'Tesis de grado de Ingeniería Civil' + ' ' *2 + '|\n')
reporte.write('+' + '-'*39 + '+\n\n')

reporte.write('1) Matriz de continuidad global: mcg\n')
with reporte as salida:
    pprint(mcg, stream = salida)
reporte = open(r'reporte_%s.txt' % g_fecha, 'a')
reporte.write('\n2) Matriz de continuidad efectiva: mcn\n')
with reporte as salida:
    pprint(mcn, stream = salida)
reporte = open(r'reporte_%s.txt' % g_fecha, 'a')
reporte.write('\n3) Matriz de continuidad de apoyos: mca\n')
with reporte as salida:
    pprint(mca, stream = salida)
reporte = open(r'reporte_%s.txt' % g_fecha, 'a')
reporte.write('\n4) Matriz de rigidez de los elementos: ke\n')
with reporte as salida:
    pprint(ke, stream = salida)
reporte = open(r'reporte_%s.txt' % g_fecha, 'a')
reporte.write('\n5) Matriz de rigidez efectiva: k_ef = (mcn)t*ke*mcn\n')
with reporte as salida:
    pprint(k_ef, stream = salida)
reporte = open(r'reporte_%s.txt' % g_fecha, 'a')
reporte.write('\n6) Vector de fuerzas globales: F_gl\n')
with reporte as salida:
    pprint(frz_gb, stream = salida)
reporte = open(r'reporte_%s.txt' % g_fecha, 'a')
reporte.write('\n7) Vector de fuerzas efectivas: F_ext\n')
with reporte as salida:
    pprint(frz_ef, stream = salida)
reporte = open(r'reporte_%s.txt' % g_fecha, 'a')
reporte.write('\n8) Vector de desplazamientos: u = inversa(k_ef)*F_ext\n')
with reporte as salida:
    pprint(u, stream = salida)
reporte = open(r'reporte_%s.txt' % g_fecha, 'a')
reporte.write('\n9) Vector de fuerzas en barras: F_bar = ke*mcn*u\n')
with reporte as salida:
    pprint(f_bar, stream = salida)
reporte = open(r'reporte_%s.txt' % g_fecha, 'a')
reporte.write('\n10) Vector de reacciones en los apoyos: Reac = (mca)t*F_bar\n')
with reporte as salida:
    pprint(reac, stream = salida)
reporte.close()
```

Now I show the entire setup.py file code:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includes = ['PyQt4.QtCore', 'PyQt4.QtGui', 'sip',     'pyqtgraph.graphicsItems','numpy','datetime','pprint'"atexit"]
excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'email', 'pywin.debugger',"cvxopt",
'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl','tables',
'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter', 'zmq','PySide','pysideuic','scipy','matplotlib']

if sys.version[0] == '2':
# causes syntax error on py2
    excludes.append('PyQt4.uic.port_v3')

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

build_exe_options = {"excludes": excludes,
    "includes":includes,"include_msvcr":True,
    'compressed':True,'copy_dependent_files':True,'create_shared_zip':True,
    'include_in_shared_zip':True,'optimize':2}

setup( name = "Test Software",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Proyecto de tesis Felipe Perez",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("maincerchas.py", base=base)])
```

I think that maybe the problem is a missing module, what you think?

Thanks for reading and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the **absolute path**.

> reporte = open(r'D:\...\reporte_%s.txt' % g_fecha, 'w')

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would thank the fast responding. It gave some ligth on my project.

After a few minutes thinking, I decided to run the program on W7 (I developed it on CAELinux, GREAT distro), and VOILA! an error came out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "maincerchas.py", line 300, in acc_ejecutar
        reporte = open(r'reporte_%s.txt' % g_fecha, 'w')
IOError: [Errno  22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'reporte_2014-08-07 18:36:37.9470000.txt'
```

Now i'm going to dig about that error, and eventually post the solution.

Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

After all, it seems that all trouble was caused by Windows reserved characters (I was trying to use colon ":" that is a reserved character on Windows)

I just added this line to my code and runs flawlessly

```
g_fecha = g_fecha.replace(':', '_')
```

Hope it will be helpfull. Happy coding!